# In Vue, use select to choose an object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a select element with options, which loops through an array of objects (**services**).

```
<select placeholder="Vælg ydelse">
    <option v-for="service in services" :key="service.id">
        {{service.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In my data object, I have

```
chosenService: {
    id: 42,
    name: "some service",
    group: {
        id: 2,
        name: "some group within the service",
    },
    additions: [],
    classSignupMoreActive: false,
},
```

Which I'd like to be retrieved once the select is changed.

Finally, I'm sending the **services** array from the parent, as all of this is happening in a component. I'm not sure if this is the most correct way to do it.

Like this:

```
<Modal
  :show="showModal"
  @close="showModal = false"
  title="Modal Title"
  :services="this.services"
>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `v-model` and pass object to `:value` property of option:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      services: [{id: 42, name: "some service", group: {id: 2, name: "some group within the service",}, additions: [], classSignupMoreActive: false,}, {id: 43, name: "some other service", group: {id: 2, name: "some group within the service",}, additions: [], classSignupMoreActive: false,}],
      chosenService: {},
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select v-model="chosenService" placeholder="Vælg ydelse">
    <option v-for="service in services" :key="service.id" :value="service">
        {{service.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  chosenService = {{ chosenService }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd tried using v-model, but didn't use :value with it which didn't make the binding probably.